Silent Installation of MySQL ODBC driver via *.msi package, or myodbc-installer.exe provided by Oracle
I try to use code from Powershell script
msiexec /i mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.30-winx64.msi /quiet

But it is not doing anything.
I try to install from *.zip package using not install.bat (for it generates user interaction windows) but directly using myodbc-installer.exe
Next command:
 ./myodbc-installer.exe -d -a -n "MySQL ODBC 9.0 Unicode Driver" -t "DRIVER=myodbc9w.dll;SETUP=myodbc9S.dll"

executed successfully:
PS D:\mysql-connector-odbc-9.0.0-winx64\bin> ./myodbc-installer.exe -d -a -n "MySQL ODBC 9.0 Unicode Driver" -t "DRIVER=myodbc9w.dll;SETUP=myodbc9S.dll"
Success: Usage count is 1
PS D:\mysql-connector-odbc-9.0.0-winx64\bin>

But I do not see newly installed driver in ODBC drivers list when execute Get-ODBCDriver comandlet by Microsoft.
PS D:\mysql-connector-odbc-9.0.0-winx64\bin> Get-ODBCdriver


Name      : Driver da Microsoft para arquivos texto (*.txt; *.csv)
Platform  : 32-bit
Attribute : {APILevel, DriverODBCVer, FileUsage, Driver...}

Name      : Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)
Platform  : 32-bit
Attribute : {APILevel, DriverODBCVer, FileUsage, Driver...}

Name      : Driver do Microsoft dBase (*.dbf)
Platform  : 32-bit
Attribute : {APILevel, DriverODBCVer, FileUsage, Driver...}

Name      : Driver do Microsoft Excel(*.xls)
Platform  : 32-bit
Attribute : {APILevel, DriverODBCVer, FileUsage, Driver...}

Name      : Driver do Microsoft Paradox (*.db )
Platform  : 32-bit
Attribute : {APILevel, DriverODBCVer, FileUsage, Driver...}

Name      : Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)
Platform  : 32-bit
Attribute : {APILevel, DriverODBCVer, FileUsage, Driver...}

Name      : Microsoft Access-Treiber (*.mdb)
Platform  : 32-bit
Attribute : {APILevel, DriverODBCVer, FileUsage, Driver...}

Name      : Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)
Platform  : 32-bit
Attribute : {APILevel, DriverODBCVer, FileUsage, Driver...}

Name      : Microsoft dBase-Treiber (*.dbf)
Platform  : 32-bit
Attribute : {APILevel, DriverODBCVer, FileUsage, Driver...}

Name      : Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)
Platform  : 32-bit
Attribute : {APILevel, DriverODBCVer, FileUsage, Driver...}

Name      : Microsoft Excel-Treiber (*.xls)
Platform  : 32-bit
Attribute : {APILevel, DriverODBCVer, FileUsage, Driver...}

Name      : Microsoft ODBC for Oracle
Platform  : 32-bit
Attribute : {APILevel, FileUsage, Driver, ConnectFunctions...}

Name      : Microsoft Paradox Driver (*.db )
Platform  : 32-bit
Attribute : {APILevel, DriverODBCVer, FileUsage, Driver...}

Name      : Microsoft Paradox-Treiber (*.db )
Platform  : 32-bit
Attribute : {APILevel, DriverODBCVer, FileUsage, Driver...}

Name      : Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)
Platform  : 32-bit
Attribute : {APILevel, DriverODBCVer, FileUsage, Driver...}

Name      : Microsoft Text-Treiber (*.txt; *.csv)
Platform  : 32-bit
Attribute : {APILevel, DriverODBCVer, FileUsage, Driver...}

Name      : SQL Server
Platform  : 32-bit
Attribute : {APILevel, FileUsage, Driver, ConnectFunctions...}

Name      : SQL Server
Platform  : 64-bit
Attribute : {APILevel, FileUsage, Driver, ConnectFunctions...}

Name      : Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)
Platform  : 64-bit
Attribute : {Driver, APILevel, FileExtns, FileUsage...}

Name      : Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)
Platform  : 64-bit
Attribute : {Driver, APILevel, FileExtns, FileUsage...}

Name      : Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)
Platform  : 64-bit
Attribute : {Driver, APILevel, FileExtns, FileUsage...}

P.S. Ironic, there is Oracle ODBC driver by default, yet MS going to get rid of it. So, question stands.
P.P.S. I've founs out that it works ONLY under elevated Admin Privileges which always ask for UAC comfirmation. A disappointment...
I try to use -Bypass argument, but with no success
$installerPath = "D:\mysql-connector-odbc-9.0.0-winx64\bin\myodbc-installer.exe"


$arguments = @(
    "-a"                # Perform Install
    "-d"                # Driver
    "MySQL ODBC 9.0 Unicode Driver" # Driver Name
    "-n"                # Имя DSN
    "MySQL ODBC 9.0 Unicode DSN"    # DSN Name
    "-t"                # DSN Connection String
    "DRIVER=MySQL ODBC 9.0 Unicode Driver"
    
    "-NoProfile" 
    
    "-ExecutionPolicy" 
    "Bypass"
)

Start-Process -FilePath $installerPath -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait

